# CFL condition of source term

Tags: finite-difference, cfl

Consider one dimensional hyperbolic pde 
$$u_t+f'(u)u_x=0$$

For the above problem ,CFL condition is $\Delta t\leq \dfrac{\Delta x}{|f'(u)|}.$

But if we include  the source term $,S(u,t),$ which depend upon $u$  and $t$ in above equation i.e.
$$u_t+f'(u)u_x=S(u,t)$$
 What is the influence of $S(u, t)$ in the CFL condition ?.

Comment: The stability of the numerical scheme depends only on the discretisation of the convection term. The source term has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: @HBR but if we have non-stiff source term, then what will happen

Comment: @ HBR I think CFL condition will be $\Delta t \leq \min\left(\dfrac{\Delta x}{|f'(u)|}, \dfrac{1}{|S'(u)|}\right)$

Comment: @Sandy Are you sure you really mean CFL here? Based on your comment above you seem to be putting all stability criteria under one label.

Comment: If the source term is $S(t)$ it does not affect the stability. If it is $S(u)$ then you can apply classical ODE stability analysis for that part and that can give you an indication of the time step required to ensure stability. However I am not sure if such a " term by term " analysis leads to a sufficient condition for stability or just a necessary one... (i.e. is it enough for all cases)